# What is difference between nn.Module and nn.Sequential

Tags: python, pytorch

I am just learning to use PyTorch as a beginner. If anyone is familiar with PyTorch, would you tell me the difference between `nn.Module` and `nn.Sequential`?

My questions are

1. What is the advantage to use `nn.Module` instead of `nn.Sequential`?
2. Which is regularly utilised to build the model?
3. How we should select `nn.Module` or `nn.Sequential`?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**TLDR; answering your questions**

> 1. What is the advantage to use `nn.Module` instead of `nn.Sequential`?

While `nn.Module` is the base class to implement PyTorch models, `nn.Sequential` is a quick way to define a sequential neural network structures inside or outside an existing `nn.Module`.

> 2. Which is regularly utilized to build the model?

Both are widely used.

> 3. How we should select `nn.Module` or `nn.Sequential`?

All neural networks are implemented with `nn.Module`. If the layers are sequentially used (`self.layer3(self.layer2(self.layer1(x)))`, you can leverage `nn.Sequential` to not have to define the `forward` function of the model.

---

I should start by mentioning that [`nn.Module`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html) is the base class for all neural network modules in PyTorch. As such [`nn.Sequential`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Sequential.html) is actually a direct subclass of `nn.Module`, you can look for yourself [on this line](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/f35f52e4a695e335c161c15246378affa524e5aa/torch/nn/modules/container.py#L43).

When creating a new neural network, you would usually go about creating a new class and inheriting from `nn.Module`, and defining two methods: `__init__` (the initializer, where you define your layers) and `forward` (the inference code of your module, where you use your layers). That's all you need, since
PyTorch will handle backward pass with [Autograd](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/autograd_tutorial.html). Here is an example of a module:

```
class NN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(10, 4)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(4, 2)

    def forward(self, x)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        return x
```

If the model you are defining is sequential, *i.e.* the layers are called sequentially on the input, one by one. Then, you can simply use a `nn.Sequential`. As I explained earlier, `nn.Sequential` is a special kind of `nn.Module` made for this particular widespread type of neural network. The equivalent here is:

```
class NN(nn.Sequential):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
           nn.Linear(10, 4),
           nn.ReLU(),
           nn.Linear(4, 2),
           nn.ReLU())
```

Or a simpler way of putting it is:

```
NN = Sequential(
   nn.Linear(10, 4),
   nn.ReLU(),
   nn.Linear(4, 2),
   nn.ReLU())
```

The objective of `nn.Sequential` is to quickly implement sequential modules such that you are not required to write the forward definition, it being implicitly known because the layers are sequentially called on the outputs.

In a more complicated module though, you might need to use multiple sequential submodules. For instance, take a CNN classifier, you could define a `nn.Sequential` for the CNN part, then define another `nn.Sequential` for the fully connected classifier section of the model.

Comment: that's the awesome explanation. Thank you for your help!